# How do I find greater number folder from root folder path using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, directory, c#-3.0

I have 3 folders in `Controllers` folder `z1` , `z2` and `z3`

how do I compare and find out `z3` is greater among all listed folders?

This code will give me folder depth .

```
public static int FolderDepth(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            return 0;
        DirectoryInfo parent = Directory.GetParent(path);
        if (parent == null)
            return 1;
        return FolderDepth(parent.FullName) + 1;
    }
```

[image]

> greater means in name like 3 is greater than 2 &1 so z3 is greater.
>   out put should be z3

Comment: What do you mean by greater? Bigger in size, contains more items, name order?

Comment: Why use 3.0 and 4.0 tag?

Comment: greater means in `name` like `3` is greater than `2 &1` so `z3` is greater. out put should be `z3`

Comment: So basically you want an directory as input and you want to see if that directory is greater (order by name) than all other ones beside the input directory?

Comment: yes there you are . like i will give folder path like `C:\mydata\Controllers`
now will check all folders inside this path and check by name if `z4` dire is present give output as `z4`

Comment: Unclear what you want, if you want to see which name is greater just gather all folder names into an array, use a sort, and then pick the last item of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var directory = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                         .OrderByDescending(dir => dir)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, you may have another problem. What is supposed to be "greater", `z15` or `z2`? And how would a computer find out? Do your folders follow a pattern?

Comment: @Neo It's the syntax of the OrderByDescending method. You get an item in the collection and you need to return what you want to order by. As I want to order by the very item that is in the collection, I return the variable that is passed.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if that is what you want but I give it a try:

```
public bool DirectoryIsGreatest(string directoryPath)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    return false;
  var parent = Directory.GetParent(directoryPath);
  if (parent == null)
    return false;
  var directoriesToCheck = Directory.GetDirectories(parent.FullName).ToList();
  directoriesToCheck.Sort();
  return directoriesToCheck[directoriesToCheck.Count - 1] == directoryPath;  
}
```